# Navigate to different pages when link is clicked

Tags: php, arrays

I have below code for `Index.php` file. Whenever the user clicks on the link from HTML page, then it redirects to the `Index.php` page. This page redirects randomly to the three different pages, namely: "index_control.php" , "index_non_intrusive.php" , "index_intrusive.php". **But, now, I want to do is like:** When the user clicks the link first it should navigate to the first link from the array(index_control.php),and when second user clicks the link, then 2nd link from the array(index_non_intrusive.php) so forth. And when the fourth user clicks on the link it should again redirect to the 1st link from array(index_control.php). so sort of sequence navigation not random. It would be great if someone can give some hint or help to achieve this.

**`Index.php`**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      abc
    </title>
  </head>

<?php
  $links= array("http://abc/index_control.php","http://abc/index_non_intrusive.php","http://abc/index_intrusive.php");
  $randomLink = $links[rand(0, count($links)-1)];
  header("Location: {$randomLink}");
  exit();
?>

<html>
```

Comment: Add a counter, add 1 per user click, then when it reaches 3, reset it back

Comment: I want to do sequence navigation because I want to assign equal number of users on each page(for ex: Total 150 users, so each page should be accessible to 50 users). In random navigation it is not possible.

Comment: If you want to know where to redirect, a counter is one way. Check whether the counter is 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: First of all, you should read this http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php and then you should be able to create your solution. But only when you have understood how Communication between Webserver and User is working.

Comment: What you want to achieve is called [A/B Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). There are countless solutions for this problem, coded in PHP or Javascript. This feature is integrated in Google Analytics (you can find it under Behaviour/Experiments) and does everything for you: it splits the incoming traffic to your index pages using the weights you configure and it shows you stats to see how each branch performs. And, bonus, there is no need to write a single line of code (apart from copy-pasting the Javascript integration code it provides).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID" (found in @Oliver's [link](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)) I believe that sessions are not the tool to evenly distribute your (*different!*) users onto different URLs. You will need a globally accessible "variable". One very simple method could be to refer to an integer value that is stored in a file and incremented after each use, like

```
<?php
  $f="filename_for_integer_value.txt"; // make sure you have write access!
  $links= array("http://abc/index_control.php",
                "http://abc/index_non_intrusive.php",
                "http://abc/index_intrusive.php");
  $n=file_get_contents($f);
  file_put_contents($f,($n+1)%count($links));
  header("Location: {$links[$n]}");
  exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save clicked count in somewhere, in the example I use simple `JSON file`. And I use `jQuery` to listen click event and send data to `PHP`.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['clicked'])){
        $links = array(
            "link1",
            "link2",
            "link3",
        );
        $clicked_count = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'),true)['clicked'];
        $clicked_count = ($clicked_count >= 2) ? 0 : $clicked_count+1;
        file_put_contents('test.json', json_encode(['clicked'=> $clicked_count]));
        header("location: {$links[$clicked_count]}");
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="button">Click</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#button').click(function(){

            // first parameter is your php file e.g. something.php, leave it blank if you use the same file
            $.post("", {clicked:true});  
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

### test.json

```
{
    "clicked":1
}
```